# constructing a string in pl/sql f

Tags: java, plsql

I want to loop that array and use it in the NOT IN part of my query.
Problem is it returns 3 records. It should return 2.
My problem is in how i am processing the array in the pl/sql

Answer (score 0):

First, the string you build in java has an extra comma in the end. You can remove it by using the flag

```
String separator = "";
for(String s : tableNamesToExclude){
       sb.append(separator).append("'").append(s.replace("'", "''")).append("',");
       separator = ",";
}
```

This way, the separator ',' is added before every element but the first one.

Second, your string that ends up in the tablenames variable is exactly the string that you've built in java (you can verify it using the dbms_output.put_line function). So the "not in" operator will check if there are any tables that have the name equal to this string, which will fail.

I think that the exact solution for your problem is described here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061

Comment: I just cant figure it out using that example, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand... You don't use java stringbuilder result in oracle at all...

Comment: Can you print out the value of tablenames after the loop?

Comment: Also, what happens if you pass the x_exclude_table_names into the "not in(...)" argument?

Comment: I cant seem to print anything from the pl/sql So i dont know what its truly doing

Comment: Just for debug purposes, try replacing the loop with tabelnames := 'STYLE' and running it... just to check if it works with a simple varchar2 variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged PLSQL i have tried to illustrate some of the techniques in which you can achieve the required output. Hope below snippet helps.

```
var  p_ref refcursor;
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
TYPE lv_var
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_tab lv_var;
  lv_str VARCHAR2(100);

  --Schema level object
  lv_num NUMBER_NTT;
  --Schema level object
BEGIN
  SELECT LEVEL ||'AV' BULK COLLECT INTO lv_tab FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
  --There are two ways in whcih you can loop
  -- 1 Just try to make a string whcih can be used in IN clause
  FOR I IN lv_tab.FIRST..lv_tab.LAST
  LOOP
    lv_str:=lv_str||','''||lv_tab(i)||'''';
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line(SUBSTR(lv_str,2,LENGTH(lv_str)));
  --This lv_str can be used in any NOT IN condition
  --2 WAY is bit more efficient but here in this case you wont bwe able to do it via PLSQL object. We need
  --  to create a schema level nested table object then then use it in NOT IN clause
  SELECT LEVEL BULK COLLECT
  INTO lv_num
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 2;
  OPEN :p_ref FOR SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT 1 NM FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 NM FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 3 NM FROM DUAL
  )A WHERE A.NM NOT IN
  (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(lv_num)
  );
END;
print p_ref;
```

Comment: I figured it out. What i needed to do was: tc.table_name NOT IN(SELECT * FROM table(names));

Comment: Ohk so if it helped can u accept the answer it would be useful to others too.